# Rsyncing multiple files with white spaces in the names

Tags: backup, whitespace, rsync

I'm trying to back up files onto a server, but I'm having problems with files that have white spaces in the names.

I'm using this command in terminal:

```
FILES="testing/space\ in\ filename testing/and\ again"; rsync -v $FILES server::address
```

`testing` is the folder, with the two files being `space in filename` and `and again`.

When I run that, I get the following result:

```
rsync: link_stat "/home/user/testing/space\" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/home/user/in\" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/home/user/filename" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/home/user/testing/and\" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/home/user/again" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

I've been looking into using the `--protect-args` option, but I haven't been able to get that working either.

Comment: Try quoting your `$FILES` variable: `rsync -v "$FILES"` (etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily change the IFS (internal field separator):

```
FILES="long filename with spaces
another one"
OLDIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
rsync -v $FILES server::address
IFS="$OLDIFS" # restores default behaviour
```

Please note, that `$'\n'` is bashism. You might try this for other Posix shells:

```
IFS="
"
```

To process multiple files just separate them by your new IFS (in the above case a newline character). Instead of the newline character you might even use any characters you like.